# Azure Builds DotNetCoreCLI@2 publish task creates unexpected folder

Tags: azure, azure-devops

I'm using the DotNetCoreCLI@2 task in Azure Builds as shown below. The results I'm getting differ from Visual Studio's default publish path by one folder.

Is there a way to change the DotNetCoreCLI@2 task so it doesn't add that extra folder? (win-x64 is the extra folder)

```
- task: DotNetCoreCLI@2
  displayName: Publish API Single File
  inputs:
    command: 'publish'
    arguments: '/p:PublishProfile=FolderProfile'
```

Azure publish log:

```
  Determining projects to restore...
  Restored C:\agent2\_work\4\s\WebApplication1\WebApplication1.csproj (in 463 ms).
  WebApplication1 -> C:\agent2\_work\4\s\WebApplication1\bin\Debug\netcoreapp3.1\win-x64\WebApplication1.dll
  WebApplication1 -> C:\agent2\_work\4\s\WebApplication1\bin\Debug\netcoreapp3.1\win-x64\publish\
```

Answer (score 1):

According to [docs](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/core/tools/dotnet-publish)

> If not specified, it defaults to `[project_file_folder]./bin/[configuration]/[framework]/publish/` for a runtime-dependent executable and cross-platform binaries. It defaults to `[project_file_folder]/bin/[configuration]/[framework]/[runtime]/publish/` for a self-contained executable.

this is correct for self-contained executable. So if this is your case and you want to publish to a different folder you should specify it using `-o|--output <OUTPUT_DIRECTORY>` option.